# Integrate Project server 2010 with CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, project-server

I have .NET experience. I am new to Project server. I have been aksed to write a plugin to interface Project server with Dynamics CRM. Could you please let me know if there is any documentation or SDK?

Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a question for Google and MSDN.

[Project Server Interface (PSI) Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms457477.aspx)

[Project 2010 SDK Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms512767.aspx)

[Dynamics CRM SDK](http://tinyurl.com/5wvwwu8)